# String numbers with $\{0,1,2\}$

Tags: combinatorics

My answer here is $405$... but Im wondering if my answer is correct or not. Any idea?

QUESTION: how many string composed of 6 numbers can be formed from $\{0,1,2\}$ without having $(0,1,2), (1,0,2)$ and $(2,0,1)$ in any part of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a different answer.

You can use inclusion-exclusion a few times to count the complement. Let $n_1, n_2, n_3$ be the number of $6$-digit strings which do contain $(0,1,2), (1,0,2), (2,0,1)$, respectively. If a string contains $(0,1,2)$, it is of the form $(0,1,2,\_,\_,\_)$, $(\_,0,1,2,\_,\_,\_)$, $(\_,\_,0,1,2,\_)$, or $(\_,\_,\_,0,1,2)$. Only one string has more than one of these forms; namely $(0,1,2,0,1,2)$, so $n_1 = 4 \cdot 3^3 - 1 = 53$. Likewise, $n_2 = n_3 = 4 \cdot 3^3 - 1 = 107$.

The only strings which contains both $(0,1,2)$ and $(1,0,2)$ are $(0,1,2,1,0,2)$ and $(1,0,2,0,1,2)$.

The only strings which contain both $(0,1,2)$ and $(2,0,1)$ are of the form $(0,1,2,2,0,1)$, $(2,0,1,0,1,2)$, $(2,0,1,2,\_,\_)$, $(\_,2,0,1,2,\_)$, $(\_,\_,2,0,1,2)$, $(0,1,2,0,1,\_)$, and $(\_,0,1,2,0,1)$. $(2,0,1,2,0,1)$ and $(0,1,2,0,1,2)$ have two of these forms, and no string has three of these forms, so there are $2 + 3 \cdot 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3 - 2 = 33$ strings which contain both $(0,1,2)$ and $(2,0,1)$.

The only strings which contain both $(1,0,2)$ and $(2,0,1)$ are of the form $(1,0,2,2,0,1)$, $(2,0,1,1,0,2)$, $(1,0,2,0,1,\_)$, $(\_,1,0,2,0,1)$, $(2,0,1,0,2,\_)$, and $(\_,2,0,1,0,2)$. No string has more than one of these forms, so there are exactly $2 + 4 \cdot 3 = 14$ such strings.

Exactly one string contains $(0,1,2)$, $(1,0,2)$, and $(2,0,1)$, namely $(1,0,2,0,1,2)$.

We conclude that the number of strings which contain $(0,1,2)$, $(1,0,2)$, or $(2,0,1)$ is $107 + 107 + 107 - 2 - 33 - 14 + 1 = 273$. There are $3^6 = 729$ total strings, so there are $456$ strings which do not contain $(0,1,2)$, $(1,0,2)$, or $(2,0,1)$.

Edit: I miscalculated $4 \cdot 3^3 - 1$ before, giving the wrong answer. The current solution is correct, as can be verified with the following Haskell code:

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

containsone s = isInfixOf [0,1,2] s || isInfixOf [1,0,2] s || isInfixOf [2,1,0] s

main = print $ length $ filter containsone $ sequence $ replicate 6 [0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $x_{ik}(n)$ the number of admissible strings of length $n\geq2$ having $ik$ as last two figures, and collect these numbers in the vector
$$x(n)=\bigl(x_{00}(n),x_{01}(n),x_{02}(n),x_{10}(n),x_{11}(n),x_{12}(n),x_{20}(n),x_{21}(n),x_{22}(n)\bigr)\ .$$
Then $x(2)=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. Considering $x(n)$ as a row vector we have the recursion
$$x(n+1)=x(n)\>A\qquad(n\geq2)$$
where $A$ is a $9\times9$ matrix encoding the forbidden and the allowed transitions from one pair $ik$ to some other pair $kl$. Since all transitions $ik\to kl$, except $01\to12$, $10\to 02$, $20\to01$, are allowed this matrix looks as follows:
$$A=\left[\matrix{
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr
}\right]\ .$$
Using Mathematica we then find
$$x(6)=x(2)\>A^4=(64, 45, 43, 57, 57, 40, 50, 50, 50)\ .$$
The sum of the $x_{ik}(6)$ is $456$, as obtained by @diracdeltafunc.